# Alerta em Campo

Tags: php, html

Fala galera.
Tenho um duvida, gostaria de saber como eu faço para exibir uma Div de alerta ao lado de um input caso esse campo não seja preenchido ou os dados informados já existam no banco de dados.`

```
        <form action="Cadastrado.php" method="POST">


            <input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Nome" class="nome" id="nometeste" >


            <input type="text" name="sobrenome" placeholder="Sobrenome" class="sobrenome" >


            <input type="text" name="login" placeholder="Email" class="login" maxlength="40" >


            <input type="password" name="senha" placeholder="Senha" class="senha" maxlength="30" >

            <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar" class="botao">

        </form>

        </div>`
```

Comment: Você pode usar o [jQuery Validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/), muito simples de usar e permite fazer validação remota, que é o que você quer fazer ao checar se os valores já estão no banco de dados.

Answer (score 0):

Para exigir que os campos sejam preenchidos você pode adicionar `required` no input. Ficaria assim:

```
<input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Nome" class="nome" id="nometeste" required>
```

Comment: Então, eu já tinha feito dessa maneira, mas ele não compara as informações com o banco de dados. Com PHP eu consigo fazer essa comparação mas não consigo mostrar uma div de alerta em vez de mostrar um alert de javascript